# JavaScript not applying to MySQL ids

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

i am trying to add video playing functions to all videos from my sql
each video has id to use for java when i view the page yes each script got its id from my sql but it not working for the rest[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKxCz.png) as u see each script got its id but when clicking play button it only plays the last one and not working for the rest

where did i go wrong

```
<?php 

         include "db_conn.php";
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY id DESC";  
         $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

         if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
            while ($video = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) { 

         ?>

     <div class="video">

       <video class="video__player" id="<?=$video['id']?>"   src="uploads/<?=$video['video_url']?>"></video>


       <script>
var id = document.getElementById("<?=$video['id']?>"); 

function playPause() { 
  if (id.paused) 
    id.play(); 
  else 
    id.pause(); 
} 

</script>

        <?php 
         }
         }else {
            echo "<h1>error getting index disco its empty</h1>";
         }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of duplicating your `playPause` function for each row, create a single function outside of the loop and pass the id into it as a parameter (or pass the element itself).

```
function playPause(id) {
  let elem=document.getElementById(id)
  if (elem.paused) 
    elem.play(); 
  else 
    elem.pause(); 
} 

<button onclick="playPause('<?=$video['id']?>')">Play</button>
```